# Get all results from mysql JOIN, even if no join matches

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am doing a JOIN operation between a table and itself. The table schema is something like:

```
| id | name | parent |
|  0 | .... |   ...  |
|  1 | .... |   ...  |
|  2 | .... |   ...  |
```

The query looks like:

```
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT t1.id AS t1id, t1.name AS t1name, t2.name AS t2name 
                            FROM cats t1 
                            JOIN cats t2 ON t1.parent = t2.id
                            WHERE t1.name IN ($qMarks)");
$stmt->execute($arr);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

So, I'm passing in an array of names `$arr`, and I am getting back the rows where there is a matching name to one of the items in the parameter array. This works fine, so long as there is also a matching `id` somewhere for `parent`.

But, sometimes the value for `parent` will be blank (empty cell). I still want to get those results, as long as the `t1.name IN ($qMarks)` condition is met.

How do I return the values, even if the `t1.parent` value in the table is blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT t1.id AS t1id, t1.name AS t1name, t2.name AS t2name 
                        FROM cats t1 
                        LEFT JOIN cats t2 ON t1.parent = t2.id
                        WHERE t1.name IN ($qMarks)");
```

Comment: Sorry, that should link to the right (left) page now.